# Tail numbers not starting with N, with domestic US carriers?

Tags: usa, aircraft-registration, statistics

I'm looking at some of the on-time performance data made public by the US Bureau of Tranport Statistics, e.g. through [here](https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=236). These have the tail numbers of the aircraft used in commercial intra-US flights over the years.

I'm seeing that, occasionally, tail numbers are missing. But in some cases they're actually garbled (e.g. `N105@@`) - or just perhaps uncommon. Specifically, I'm seeing, among others, tail numbers such as:

```
89869E 
91469E 
9149E  
A367NW 
EI-BWD 
HZO    
M67153
```

Can some of these be "legit"? That is, could the above (and similar) strings be actual tail numbers of aircraft which were used in commercial domestic US flights?

---

Note that we're talking about entries from years between 2001 and 2008.

Comment: Nearly all countries’ tail numbers start with an ITU prefix, and EI- is for Ireland. The others all appear to be garbage data.

Comment: [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27374/62) seems closely related and might answer your question? At least about whether it’s possible for non-US aircraft to be used in domestic commercial operations.

Comment: @Pondlife: It might explain one (or some?) of the tailnums, but not all of them I think.

Comment: A367NW looks garbled. There's an N367NW which is a former Northwest Airlines A320.

Comment: To get better answers, you might like to clarify if you're asking a) if it's possible that non-US aircraft are being used for domestic commercial flights (already answered in the question I linked to); b) if the specific tail numbers you listed are, were or could be real; or c) something else?

Comment: @Pondlife: See edit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is commercial domestic service using foreign registry aircraft allowed in the USA?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27374/is-commercial-domestic-service-using-foreign-registry-aircraft-allowed-in-the-us)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these *can* be legit.  For example, `EI-` means the aircraft is registered in Ireland.  Others look corrupt, though.  `HZ-AAA` is Saudi Arabia, but your HZ example looks too short.  The examples starting with four numbers don't match any country's pattern.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_registration_prefixes

The examples here that start with a string of digits all resolve to actual aircraft, if you prepend an N to them.  (Commenter Ralph J suggested this.)

Corrupt data wouldn't be too surprising.  For 2005, for example, 15000 of the 594000 entries had no tail number at all.

Comment: What would the digits+E numbers mean?

Comment: @einpoklum Could be military

Comment: @einpoklum or coordinates rather than aircraft registration codes or flight numbers

Comment: @jwenting: It's the "tail number" column of the on-time performance data; and there is no column with coordinates...

Comment: @einpoklum doesn't mean it's correct :)

Comment: I'd presume that anything that's 5 characters without a leading N or other obvious explanation like the EI-xxx example is simply a case where the N was omitted.  So when you have 1234X, I'd presume that this is meant to be N1234X, unless a better explanation is found.  If you find the same aircraft showing up multiple times as both 1234X and N1234X then I'd say you have confirmation that it's just a missing N in the certain cases.  Sounds like you have moderately low-quality data you're working with.