# Can a Pilot hold multiple foreign licenses and practice the privileges of it in each country?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, caa-uk-regulations, cpl, casa-regulations

Is it possible for a CASA CPL holder to convert to both an FAA and CAAUK license and hold all three at the same time?

Would the pilot then be qualified to exercise the privileges of the CPL in Australia (with a CASA registered aircraft), USA (With an FAA registered aircraft), and the UK (With a CAAUK registered aircraft)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a pilot can hold multiple licences from different authorities, but it's not about operating in a country. A license from an authority applies to aircraft **registered** with that authority, wherever that aircraft is in the world.

An FAA license lets you operate an N registered aircraft anywhere in the world, it does not let you operate a foreign registered aircraft on American soil unless that foreign authority gives permission to do so.

Comment: There is no confusion @Samuel, I'm answering your question.

Comment: But does the training for those licenses have to be started from scratch or can they be converted?

Comment: It depends @Samuel. That question has been asked on this site before, you might want to search on the word convert. I'd look myself for you but I'm not in a position to at the moment, hopefully some of the helpful people on this site will comment with some links - hint hint!

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect: an FAA certificate is valid for a foreign aircraft in the US. See [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3667/62)

Comment: Not by default @Pondlife, you have to get permission from the foreign authority.

Comment: Actually, Pondlife is correct, *as long as it remains within U.S. airspace* and does not operate internationally.  Within our borders, FAA rules apply, and the answer that Pondlife linked to includes the appropriate regulation.

Comment: That might be okay with the FAA, but not the foreign authority @Lnafziger. There may be nothing they can do about it but that isn't the question.

Comment: @GdD Well, the question wasn't about this aspect either, it was just about holding the licenses and operating aircraft within their respective countries.  Since your last sentence is apparently causing some disagreement, I'd suggest considering removing it (since it wasn't an aspect that was asked about anyway), and bringing the discussion to the question to which Pondlife linked so that we can (hopefully) come to a definitive answer, over where that exact question was asked.